# Is there a minimum sleep for free heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku

on several websites it says that a free heroku dyno needs to sleep a minimum of 6hrs a day. (It says this for example at http://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/ )
But I can't find any information about this on the heroku website. Is this rule still active?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heroku changed their [free dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours) a couple of months ago. Rather than per application limits (such as the 6 hours of sleeping per day) there is now a per account limit. This limit is 550 free dyno hours per month (increased to 1000/month if you have verified your account with a credit card.

You don't have to sleep a certain number of hours a day (and you may not have to sleep at all) but if you run out then your free dynos will sleep until the end of the month.